# Spring batch partitioning taking to much time for processing 100000 records

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I want to read 10 billions of data using spring batch program. I implemented partitioning for processing for one big file.

How I can increase the performance?

Below is my configuration.

```
@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader<RequestDTO> reader() throws MalformedURLException {
    FlatFileItemReader<RequestDTO> itemReader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
    itemReader.setLineMapper(lineMapper());
    itemReader.setResource(new FileSystemResource(fileLocation));
    itemReader.setLinesToSkip(1);
    return itemReader;
}

/**
 * This is used for mapping values.
 * 
 * @return LineMapper will be returned
 */
@Bean
public LineMapper<RequestDTO> lineMapper() {
    DefaultLineMapper<RequestDTO> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();
    DelimitedLineTokenizer lineTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
    lineTokenizer.setNames("name", "salary", "company");
    lineTokenizer.setIncludedFields(0, 1, 2);
    lineTokenizer.setDelimiter(ProcessorConstants.FILE_SEPERATOR);
    BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<RequestDTO> fieldSetMapper = new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<>();
    fieldSetMapper.setTargetType(RequestDTO.class);
    lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(lineTokenizer);
    lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(fieldSetMapper);
    return lineMapper;
}

@Bean
public CRSItemProcessor processor() {
    return new CRSItemProcessor();
}
@Bean
public RepositoryItemWriter<AdministrationRequest> writer(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new RepositoryItemWriterBuilder<CRSAdministrationRequest>().methodName("saveAndFlush")
            .repository(processorBatchDAO).build();
}




@Bean
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(20);
        taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(10);
        taskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(5);
        taskExecutor.afterPropertiesSet();
        return taskExecutor;
}


@Bean(name = "partitionerJob")
public Job partitionerJob(JobCompletionNotificationListener listener) throws UnexpectedInputException, MalformedURLException, ParseException {
  return jobBuilderFactory.get("partitionerJob").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).listener(listener)
    .start(partitionStep())
    .build();
}




@Bean

public Step partitionStep() throws UnexpectedInputException, MalformedURLException, ParseException {
      return stepBuilderFactory.get("partitionStep")
        .partitioner(slaveStep(null))
        .partitioner("slaveStep",new CustomMultiResourcePartitioner())
        .gridSize(20)
        .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
        .build();
}


@Bean
public Step slaveStep(RepositoryItemWriter<CRSAdministrationRequest> writer) throws UnexpectedInputException, MalformedURLException, ParseException {
  return stepBuilderFactory.get("slaveStep")
    .<RequestDTO, AdministrationRequest>chunk(1000)
    .reader(reader())
    .processor(processor())
    .writer(writer)
    .build();
}
```

Below is custom partitioning class.

```
public class CustomMultiResourcePartitioner implements Partitioner {

    /**
     * Assign the filename of each of the injected resources to an
     * {@link ExecutionContext}.
     *
     * @see Partitioner#partition(int)
     */
    @Override
    public Map<String, ExecutionContext> partition(int gridSize) {
        Map<String, ExecutionContext> result = new HashMap<String, ExecutionContext>();

        int range = 1000;
        int fromId = 1;
        int toId = range;

        for (int i = 1; i <= gridSize; i++) {
            ExecutionContext value = new ExecutionContext();

            System.out.println("\nStarting : Thread" + i);
            System.out.println("fromId : " + fromId);
            System.out.println("toId : " + toId);

            value.putInt("fromId", fromId);
            value.putInt("toId", toId);

            // give each thread a name, thread 1,2,3
            value.putString("name", "Thread" + i);

            result.put("partition" + i, value);

            fromId = toId + 1;
            toId += range;

        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Title says 100k, question says 10 billion. That's quite a difference.

Comment: Actually first I want to try 100000 records. If it's optimize then I will go with billions data.

Comment: Reduce the chunk size and use `save` instead of `saveAndFlush`. Also what is slow in this, is it really slow or in your mind is it slow? Also you might want to use a step or job listener to prevent flushes from happening (i.e. setting the flush mode to manual instead of the default auto).

Comment: `taking too much time` is relative. What is your base line? What is taking too much time? Have isolated the most expensive part?

Comment: base line is that we can process 100000 in 2.5 min

Comment: If you process that much of data, i would not use Partition. I would try with different approach

Comment: ok, Which approach you will recommend.

Comment: Hi All, I am trying this with multi threading and able to complete 1.1 million records in 60 min. Is it good result or I can also do more optimization.